# Сериализовать данные из JTable

Tags: java, swing

Хочу сохранить данные из таблицы `JTable` и, соответственно, восстановить их при новом запуске программы. В коде инициализирована таблица `table`. Пытаюсь сериализовать содержимое с помощью следующего кода, но не выходит.

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
try {
    File file = new File("filename");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(model);
    oos.flush();
    oos.close();
} catch (IOException ex) {}
```

Ошибок много:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.paintRegion(SynthLookAndFeel.java:371)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.update(SynthLookAndFeel.java:335)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthRootPaneUI.update(SynthRootPaneUI.java:119)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:780)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5210)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:290)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1272)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5158)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4969)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:831)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:789)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:738)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:64)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1732)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel$Handler.repaintIfBackgroundsDiffer(SynthLookAndFeel.java:965)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel$Handler.propertyChange(SynthLookAndFeel.java:926)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:327)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:263)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.firePropertyChange(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1493)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.setGlobalFocusOwner(KeyboardFocusManager.java:575)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:659)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4760)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.swing.GroupLayout
```

Таблица содержит данные типов `String` и `boolean`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причиной проблемы стал `java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.swing.GroupLayout` в автоматически сгенерированном NetBeans коде. Решить данную проблему удалось, разбив содержимое таблицы на двумерный массив `Object[][]` и сериализовав/десериализовав именно его с последующей передачей в конструктор `DefaultTableModel` при новых запусках программы.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно дело в имени файла, так работает

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[]args){
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"поле1","поле2"},0);
        modelSerialize(model);
    }

    private static void modelSerialize(TableModel model){
        File file = new File("D:/test_model_serialize.txt");
        try (
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)){
            oos.writeObject(model);
            oos.flush();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Вроде, нет. В папке проекта нашел файл filename, filename.out и filename.txt -- все три, что пытался использовать. Все наполнены примерно одинаковым содержимым, но не только  таким `AC ED 00 05 73 72 `, а еще и таким `\00selectionBackgroundq\00~\00L\00`, и дело, как мне кажется, не в кодировке. Стоило ли отметить, что я пользуюсь NetBeans в Ubuntu?

Comment: А что вы там ожидали увидеть?

Comment: Справедливо. Я ожидал увидеть только первое. Заметил вот эту строку `java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.swing.GroupLayout` и понял, что дело, скорее всего, в [этом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50441006/java-io-notserializableexception-javax-swing-grouplayout?rq=1), но мой `GroupLayout` инициализируется в нередактируемом, автоматически сгенерированном участке кода.